# Bring map marker to front in Android Google Map

Tags: android, maps

I have an Android app that displays multiple markers on a Google Map (using the Google Android APIs). When multiple markers overlap each other, I want the one a user clicks on to be brought to the front (think zIndex) but I haven't found a way to do this in Android.

Is there a simple way to force a selected marker to be brought to the front of the map? Or do I need to create a new overlay with just the single selected marker and place it on top of the overlay that has all the other markers?

Or do I need to reorder the overlays in my list and then force a redraw of all the markers?

Answer (score 2):

zIndex in Google Map I think is simply done by the ordering of the overlays per the [documentation](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#getOverlays%28%29).

To achieve your functionality, create a new single overlay containing only the clicked item. Basically you will just move from the original overlay to this one.

Steps:

- Create empty overlay initially for the item that the users click. Let's call this one ClickedOverlay and put this one on top
- As the user click a particular overlay, move from the original to ClickedOverlay
- Using this method, you are not creating overlay with single item for every marker that the user click and you don't have to change the order of the overlay.